# Resetting all key maps in Vim

Tags: vim

Is there a command that resets key mappings to their default values?

For **all of them**, not just for one key.

or a plugin maybe?

Answer (score 22):

You can remove all mappings for certain modes by running some of the `mapclear` family of commands.

This is taken from `:h mapclear`

```
:mapc[lear]                     mapmode-nvo             :mapc   :mapclear
:nmapc[lear]                    mapmode-n               :nmapc  :nmapclear
:vmapc[lear]                    mapmode-v               :vmapc  :vmapclear
:xmapc[lear]                    mapmode-x               :xmapc  :xmapclear
:smapc[lear]                    mapmode-s               :smapc  :smapclear
:omapc[lear]                    mapmode-o               :omapc  :omapclear
:mapc[lear]!                    mapmode-ic              :mapc!  :mapclear!
:imapc[lear]                    mapmode-i               :imapc  :imapclear
:lmapc[lear]                    mapmode-l               :lmapc  :lmapclear
:cmapc[lear]                    mapmode-c               :cmapc  :cmapclear
                        Remove ALL mappings for the modes where the map
                        command applies.  {not in Vi}
                        Use the <buffer> argument to remove buffer-local
                        mappings :map-<buffer>
                        Warning: This also removes the default mappings.
```

One command to remove everything is

```
:mapclear | mapclear <buffer> | mapclear! | mapclear! <buffer>
```

Comment: This seems to  break plugins

Comment: @Woofas I don't see why it wouldn't it removing mapping which plugins put in.

Comment: how to remove only those defined by me?

Comment: Learning all these modes are a good todo list for me for later